# Optimal Way to Pass C# Variables to JS

Tags: c#, javascript

I have several functions that are written in JS that do error checking on my site.  On one instance I want to disable two of the checks if a certain instance in the DB is true.

I have something like this on the aspx.cs

```
if (this.exemptcheck == true) {
  // could set a variable to pass or whatever is optimal here
}
```

Then in JS I have a function like this in my .aspx

```
if (NotANumberCheck(item.GetMember("TotalSpace").Value, 'Space must be Numeric') == false) { return false; }
```

I don't want this check to run if this.examptcheck returns true.  What is the optimal way to do this?  I have heard of putting variables in non-visible fields but that doesn't seem ideal.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Side-note: It is typically discouraged to check boolean values explicitly for being equal to true or false. A boolean value is already a boolean value. At least in C# and JS, it should not be a problem though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just register your js function only if your condition is true, you don't need to check a variable:

C# code:

```
if (this.exemptcheck == true) {
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "KEY", "/* code of your JS function that handle the true case */", true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the aspx, set a member variable called ExemptCheck.  Later, in the JS, do this:

```
var exemptCheck = <% Response.Write(ExemptCheck.ToString()) %>;
```

This will give you a JS variable with the same value as the C# variable.

Comment: I have this in my aspx.cs

    private void pageSetup(EventArgs args) {
      Boolean exemptCheck;
      if (dss.ExemptCheck == true) {
        exemptCheck = true;
      }
    }

I put the following in my JS 
    function onInsert(item) {
      var exemptCheck = <% Response.Write(exemptCheck.ToString()); %>;
   }

This gives me the following error 

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'exemptCheck' does not exist in the current context

Is this a scope issue or am i doing something else wrong?

Comment: It's a scope issue.  exemptCheck needs to be a member variable of the entire page object, not just the pageSetup function; the code between the <% %> is executed during the page render function, long after your pageSetup function has exited.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a script section in the page which sets a variable to true/false and then check for that variable in the JS later.

Answer (score 0):

You may Response.Write() the javascript code only when this.examptcheck is true.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following command to set the value in the aspx.cs code

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", "var stackedUnknownExemptCheck = true;", true);